# How do I specify a serial port in the following python script using sys.argv and serial?

Tags: python, python-2.7, bluetooth, serial-port

I am relatively new to python, and am trying to specify a bluetooth serial port to be used with a script I obtained from GitHub (https://github.com/ShimmerResearch/tinyos-shimmer/blob/e04d83d9df615fc5f49f43765642cd59e979503e/apps/SimpleGSR/simpleGsr.py). I am on a mac and want to specify a bluetooth device whose port looks like this: "/dev/tty.XXXX-XXX-XXX". So far all of my attempts result in the "no device specified" error provided by the program. How to I embed my serial port path into this script?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, struct, array, time, serial

def wait_for_ack():
   ddata = ""
   ack = struct.pack('B', 0xff) 
   while ddata != ack:
   ddata = ser.read(1)
return

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
   print "no device specified"
   print "You need to specifiy the serial port of the shimmer you wish to connect to"
   print "example:"
   print "  getBtStreamVersion.py Com5"
   print " or"
   print "  getBtStreamVersion.py /dev/rfcomm0"

   print
else:
ser = serial.Serial(sys.argv[1], 115200)
ser.flushInput()
```

Thanks for your help and sharing your expertise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass it as an argument into the script when you run it, like this: `python getBtStreamVersion.py /dev/tty.XXXX-XXX-XXX`

Or, if you want to hard-code your serial port into the program (not recommended), you can replace the following:

```
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
   print "no device specified"
   print "You need to specifiy the serial port of the shimmer you wish to connect to"
   print "example:"
   print "  getBtStreamVersion.py Com5"
   print " or"
   print "  getBtStreamVersion.py /dev/rfcomm0"

   print
else:
    ser = serial.Serial(sys.argv[1], 115200)
    ser.flushInput()
```

with this:

```
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/tty.XXXX-XXX-XXX", 115200)
ser.flushInput()
```

sys.argv[1] is just getting the first command-line argument that you're passing to the script.